# How to use SafeArea in every route?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to set SafeArea once for every route?
For now I have no idea how to do that nor found such question. 
Do I have to put it every screen view?

Answer (score 3):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `builder` of `MaterialApp`

code snippet

```
MaterialApp(
    title: 'Builder Demo',
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: child,
      );
    },
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Builder Demo',
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
      return SafeArea(
        child: child,
      );
    },
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: {
      '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
      '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
    },
  ));
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate to the second screen using a named route.
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            // Navigate back to the first screen by popping the current route
            // off the stack.
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```